# property of vector-space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I don't know how can I  to prove the following (this isn't homework, i'm just flipping through a book):

if $a\in F$, $v\in V$, and $av=0$.

then $a=0$ or $v=0$.

Comment: Assume $av = 0$.  If $a = 0$ you're done; otherwise, by the field axioms there is $b \in F$ with $ba = 1$; then the vector space axioms imply that $v = 1v = (ba)v = b(av) = b(0) = 0$ and you're done.  [The fact that $b0 = 0$ may itself require proof.]

Comment: anon, thank you wish i could give you rep for your reply. from your answer i was able to see how to begin proving such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it hasn't been proven already, try proving the preliminary facts that $0_Fv=0_V$ and $a0_V=0_V$ for $a\in F$ and $v\in V$. This follows by using that fact that $0=0+0$ (for both the zero element of $F$ and of $V$), and using distributivity.

If $a=0$, you are done. So suppose $a\neq 0$, and hence has a multiplicative inverse. Try multiplying both sides of your equation by the inverse of $a$, and recall the axiom that $1v=v$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $F$, to get your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you yunone ) I wasn't too sure how to tackle this

Comment: @Krolique Sure, I'm glad it helped.